# how to compute a dexpr algorithmically in ILOG CPLEX

Tags: optimization, model, cplex, ilog

I am still a begginer on IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimisation Studio.

I'm doing the modelisation of an hospital.

I have some decision variable that correspond to :

```
dvar alpha[Operations][Rooms] in 0..1;
```

alpha[o][r] is equal to 1 if the operation o is done in the room r.

I also have a lot of other decision variable that correspond to :
in which order does the surgeon does his operations, what equipement does he use for that operation, ...

with all of that, i have enough information to compute the starting time of each operation
and i want to have a deduction variable that correspond to the time at which each operation start.

This "time[Operations]" variable, has to be computed in a specific order (you have to compute the starting time of the first operation of a room before being able to compute the second one).

the formula that compute the time is way to complex to be written in one line of a dexpr and i don't know to make an "execute" bloc having to call itself each time it generate new values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use logical constraints

```
range Operations=0..2;
range Rooms=1..4;

dvar int alpha[Operations][Rooms] in 0..1;
dvar int time[Operations];

subject to
{
  forall(r in Rooms, ordered o1,o2 in Operations) 
   ((alpha[o1][r]==1) && (alpha[o2][r]==1)) => time[o1]+10<=time[o2];
}
```

But you could also have a look at [scheduling within CPLEX](https://www.ibm.com/products/ilog-cplex-optimization-studio/cplex-cp-optimizer) . Then you would use intervals and maybe the model could work much better

Comment: Thanks !
so that mean no way of having an execute block calling itself at each step of the model :(

Comment: No the exécute blocks that are after the subject to are post processing  and are run after you get your solution

Comment: @Marcocorico sounds like you are misunderstanding what CPLEX does. You do not want to calculate the decision variable values in your own code. There is no need for them to be calculated in any specific order. There is no need for your code to calculate stuff 'at each step of the model' You DO need to specify the sets of decisions (i.e. the set sof decision variables) and the conditions and relations between them that are required for a solution to be valid (the constraints). Then CPLEX will search and find values for your variables that satisfy your constraints.